# How to convert results of a group by into a json using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following question:
If I have this data in a table:

[image]

How could you get a result like this:

[image]

I'm not a JAVA developer, excuse me if the question is very simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a java. Assuming you have a select method that return list of above objects by user name like `getObjectByUser("ALBERTO")` then you can do the following

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = getObjectByUser("ALBERTO").stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getDay, MyObject::getPools);
```

then you can use library like Jackson or Gson to convert above `Map` to JSON